# Is there an algorithm that can get the minimal element of a min-heap in O(log* n)?

Tags: data-structures, sorting, arrays, heaps

I came across this question when studying for an exam:

given a min-heap that has no prime numbers in it, is there an algorithm that can get and delete the minimum of that heap in O(log* n) ?

The answer simply said no because in this case we can sort an array in o(n log n) which we’ve learned isn’t possible without additional data.. but I can’t see how exactly is it possible to sort an array in o(n log n) if the algorithm only works if the heap has no prime numbers…

Edited:
The question asks “is there an algorithm as such”? Logically speaking the answer is no, but I couldn’t understand why? they tried to refute it by saying had there been such an algorithm we would’ve been able to sort an array in o(n log n) which isn’t possible. I think whether the algorithm works on prime numbers matters, if it works on all numbers then no matter what the input is, I can create a heap in O(n) and then get the value of delMin in O(log* n) n times aka O(n log* n) which is o(n log n), but since the said algorithm only works on non-prime numbers then I don’t think it’s possible to refute the statement.

Comment: What is a "primary number"? Do you mean a **prime** number? Also are you saying that you know an algorithm that can sorts an array of numbers that doesn't contain prime numbers in o(n log n)? I don't really think that having or not prime numbers in the input matters at all. For every input containing prime numbers you can easily map the values to a new input without prime numbers such that all the comparison relationships stay the same, so I don't think prime numbers matter in sorting

Comment: But you can’t find prime numbers in O(1) right?

Comment: First of all thank you for the note sorry English isn’t my first language :)

Comment: Why would it matter that numbers are primes or not?

Comment: The question asks “is there an algorithm as such”? Logically the answer is no,but I couldn’t understand why? they tried to refute it by saying had there been such an algorithm we would’ve been able to sort an array in o(n log n) which isn’t possible. I think whether the algorithm works on prime numbers matters, if it works on all numbers then no matter what the input is, I can create a heap in O(n) and then get the value of delMin in O(log* n) n times aka O(n log* n) which is o(n log n), but since the said algorithm only works on non-prime numbers then I don’t think it’s possible to refute it.

Comment: @Alina It's not relevant how hard it is to find prime numbers. My point is that, if your algorithm is comparison based whether the numbers are `A=[10, 12, 14]` or `B=[3, 5, 7]` the algorithm should perform *exactly* the same comparisons because for every index `i` the values `A[i]` and `B[i]` have the same "rank", so the result of comparing `A[i]` with the other values in `A` is the same as comparing `B[i]` with the other values in `B`. So prime numbers don't change anything in terms of comparisons.

Comment: Then again, you **can** have algorithms **not** based on comparisons (e.g. counting & radix sort), in which case the actual values can change the result.. but 1) I've never heard of such an algorithm that has some peculiarity for primes 2) These algorithms **do not have an O(n log n) lowerbound**. From your question it seems clear we are in the setting of comparison algorithms

Comment: If you multiply every element in the array by 4 (which takes $O(n)$), then there are no prime elements in the new array. You can do that without knowing which (if any) of the original elements was prime.

Answer (score 0):

There are n! permutations how an array of n numbers could be arranged. To sort an array, you need to rearrange items so that they are in sorted order, and for every permutation a different rearrangement is needed. Every decision you make cuts the number of possibilities by half in the best case. Therefore any comparison-based sorting algorithm needs at least $\log_2 (n!)$ comparisons. A very good estimate for n! is $n! ≈ n^n e^{-n} \sqrt (2 \pi n)$, and the base two logarithm is about $n (\log_2 (n/e))$ which is $\Theta (n \log n)$. So that's the fastest possible time for sorting.

Building a min-heap takes n steps, and you can easily sort an array by building a min-heap and extracting the smallest element n times. It follows that the average time to extract the smallest element must be $\Theta (\log n)$. It cannot be smaller, or we would have a sorting algorithm that is faster than possible.